# What trig identities are used to solve $4\sin θ\cos θ(\cos^2θ−\sin^2θ)=2\sin(2θ)\cos(2θ)$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to follow the answer from this question - [Verifying $\sin 4θ=4\cos^3 θ \sin θ - 4\cos θ \sin^3θ$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2671753/verifying-sin-4%ce%b8-4-cos3-%ce%b8-sin-%ce%b8-4-cos-%ce%b8-sin3%ce%b8)

and I'm referencing the trig identities from the Khan academy website here - https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/x9e81a4f98389efdf:trig/x9e81a4f98389efdf:using-trig-id/a/trig-identity-reference

but I'm having trouble finding out how the equation $4\sin θ\cos θ(\cos^2θ−\sin^2θ)=2\sin(2θ)\cos(2θ)$ is solved.

Comment: Using complex analysis or $t=\tan(x/2)$ **always** works for these questions

Comment: The equation in the title and Question body is not an identity.  At $\theta = \pi/4$, $4 \sin \theta \cos \theta(\cos(2\theta) - \sin(2\theta) = -2$ but $2 \sin(2\theta)\cos(2\theta) = 0$.

Comment: Typesetting issue:  OP probably meant $^2$ but wrote it as $2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sin4\theta&=2\color{blue}{\sin2\theta}\color{red}{\cos2\theta}\\
&=2(\color{blue}{2\sin\theta\cos\theta})(\color{red}{\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta})\\
&=4\sin\theta\cos\theta(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)
\end{align}

Does this help?